# jquery not working for dynamic controls

Tags: jquery

I have two html tables below:

```
<table id="Schools" align="center" valign="top">
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <table id="SchoolControls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            </table>
            <table id="ControlsSch" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            </table>
            <input id="AddSch" type="button" value="Add" />
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And I am using these tables for creating dynamic controls in it and i.e below

```
<% @user_education.each do |user_edu| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#AddSch").click(function() {
                var field = $("#field").val();
                var DDL_fromProfession = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

                var DDL_ToProfession = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


                var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
                + DDL_fromProfession + " to " + DDL_ToProfession + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
                newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


                var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);
            });

            $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
                return false;
            });
            $('#<%= SchoolControls.ClientID %>').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch1', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#<%=SchoolControls.ClientID %> tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) +           ')').remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting error the below error at this line `$('#<%= SchoolControls.ClientID %>').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch1', function()`

> NameError in Settings#new
>
> uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::SchoolControls

Kidle help me to resolve it, waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
$('#<%= SchoolControls.ClientID %>')
```

to:

```
$('#SchoolControls')
```

so you need to use:

```
$('#SchoolControls').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch1', function() {
```

and:

```
$('#SchoolControls tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have delegated the event properly but selector seems to be wrong, try this:

```
$('#SchoolControls')
```

instead of:

```
 $('#<%= SchoolControls.ClientID %>')
```